# LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded with Dota 2

Tags: 14.04, primus

When I try to run Dota 2 with `primusrun`, it gives me this error,

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/aleks/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.

malloc: unknown:0: assertion botched
free: called with unallocated block argument
last command: (null)
Aborting...Aborted (core dumped)
Game removed: AppID 570 "Dota 2", ProcID 28915 
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1411443970)
```

and it only happens when I use `primusrun` with `steam`.

Comment: What's the output of `uname -m` and `file /home/aleks/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so` ?

Comment: @lemonsqueeze Got the same problem. Output `x86_64` and `/home/chiel/.steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so
/home/chiel/.steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so: ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=c186d8f71cb1e7e6c8c53343061f30161581f787, not stripped`